# iOS release memory issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a problem when I define a UILabel add it to a UIView

```
UIView *dwView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 975.0, 620)];
UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 160.0, 950.0, 
170.0)];
# i add many UILabel in dwView 
...
UILabel *label1
UILabel *label2
UILabel *label3
...
dwView.addView(lable1);
dwView.addView(lable2);
dwView.addView(lable3);
dwView.addView(...);
[lable1 release];
[lable2 release];
[lable3 release];
[... release];
```

No matter where I define the label, I release it with the method:

```
[lable1 release];
lable1 = nil;
```

I log the retainCount, its all 0, but I checked the memory with the profile->allocations it's still not reducing.

I want to know why it is like this, and how I can reduce the memory.

**edit 1: I built my project with ARC**

**edit 2:**

now I define variable in .h

```
{
UIView *dwView;

UILabel *label1,lable2;
}
```

Init in .m

```
{

    dwView=[[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 975.0, 620)] autorelease];

    label1 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 160.0, 950.0, 170.0)] autorelease];

    label1.text = wordString;

    dwView.addView(lable1);



}



-(void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    label1 = nil;
    dwView = nil;
}
```

I try the code above, it doesn’t work.

So: how can i release the variable `dwView` and `lable1`
edit

Comment: Where do you call this: [lable1 release]; lable1 = nil; is it in dealloc? I assume you work without ARC?

Comment: The retainCount is 0. So i think it's already dealloc, Yes, I build my project with ARC.

Comment: It is not possible to use `release` with ARC.

Comment: You will never see a retain count of zero on a valid object.  If you see a retain count of zero, it's probably because your object reference is actually nil.

Comment: I use ARC, but it doesn't work. so i write the code `release`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer: Use ARC.

If you're determined to use manual reference counting, a few things:

Looking at retainCount is not useful. It will just confuse you. (You can't see pending autoRelease calls)

In your code, you are creating label1 as a local variable. Then you show ..., meaning you have code somewhere else. If you define a new local variable label1 (and you switch to "lable1" (different spelling) it will be nil. If you want to be able to get to label1 to add it to a superview and/or release it, you either need to do it in the same method/scope, or make it an instance variable.

Another option would be to autoRelease your label after creating it, then add it to the view you want to add it to. That will only work if you add it to your view before the current autoRelease pool is drained.

Comment: I update my question, would you please give me some more detail suggestions about this.

Comment: In your edit, you say "I try the code above, it doesn’t work." It doesn't work is not helpful. What doesn't work? What, exactly, is your program doing? Is it giving compile errors? Crashing? Is your memory footprint growing as you run it? BTW, your "code" is a mess, with different spellings of variable names and other typos that make it clear this is not real, running code. Don't do that. Post your actual code that is having problems. Otherwise there is no way your readers will be able to tell what is really going on.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is using **Allocations**. It doesn't accurately tell you how much live memory you're using. For that you should be using **Activity Monitor**.

Comment: It'll show you how much memory your application is actually using.

Answer (score -2):

It's better to use ARC. Otherwise use autoRelease at the end of your declaration. For example,

```
UILabel *label1 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 160.0, 
950.0,170.0)]autorelease];
```

otherwise release those with

`dealloc() label = nil;`

Comment: Don't need to autorelease *and* dealloc an object yourself.

Comment: Please try to give the solution only. Please don't focus on others errors.:x